# How to prevent Bootstrap-Vue pagination from automatically resetting

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have multiple views and I want to save state on each one, so the user doesn't have to do the same things again.

On one of them, I have a table and I use the bootstrap-pagination component for pagination, so when the user changes page, I send the request to a server for new data. I am storing sort and filter parameters in Vuex and it works well.

But when I want to save the current page like that, bootstrap-pagination changes it to 1 every time when I change view and go back.
Is it possible to prevent that behavior?

Here is code in HTML:

```
<b-pagination v-if="currentPage!=-1"
            v-model="currentPage"
            :total-rows="totalRows"
            :per-page="perPage"
            aria-controls="my-table"
            pils
            align="center"
            class="ml-auto mr-auto"
          ></b-pagination>
```

and code in javascript:

```
  data: function () {
      return {
        ...
        currentPage: this.$store.state.currentPage,
        ...
      }
    },

    ...

    watch: {
        currentPage: function(){
                this.$store.commit('updateCurrentPage', this.currentPage);
                this.getData();
              },
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issues you're facing is most likely to do with the order of how your data is loaded and set.

When your component gets initialized, you set the `currentPage` page property immediately, while (I'm guessing) setting the `totalRows` property at some time later, after fetching your data from your database.

This causes issues because the pagination will think there's 0 rows. So when you set it to page 5. It will check the `perPage` and `totalRows` properties, and since there is no page 5 (yet), it will automatically set `currentPage` back to page 1.

Instead, i would recommend you set the `currentPage` to the value from your store AFTER you've retrieved your data and set the `totalRows` property. This should fix the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Damn that's unfortunate. Using your solution I set the `totalRows` first and then did a `this.$nextTick(() =>` and set my `currentPage` in the callback. And it works now. This seems like a bug, or at least a smell.

Comment: The issue is absolutely related to the `totalRows` value. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another work around is to put a `v-if` on the pagination element that checks that `totalRows` has been set. This causes the pagination element to be rendered after the `totalRows` value is known. It is useful when you are loading the data using AJAX and don't know the number of row ahead of time.

e.g.

```
<b-pagination
  v-if="totalRows > 0"
  v-model="currPage"
  :total-rows="totalRows"
  :per-page="perPage"
  aria-controls="my-table"
  size="sm"
  limit="7"
  first-number
  last-number
  >
</b-pagination>
```

Comment: Added `v-if="totalRows > 0"` works for me. Grate!